# Python multiprocessing: recovering error message from a child process that unexpectedly crashes

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Consider the following code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
from queue import Empty


def function(i, argument):
    return i, argument


def worker(jobs, results, argument):
    while True:
        try:
            val = jobs.get(timeout=1.)
        except Empty:
            return
        else:
            results.put(function(i, agrument))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    jobs = mp.Queue()
    for i in range(10):
        jobs.put(i)
    results = mp.Queue()

    processes = []
    for k in range(4):
        proc = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(jobs, results, k))
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)

    res = results.get()
```

When I execute this code in an IPython console (within spyder IDE, and using python 3.11.5) the console freezes. I understand that the child processes crashed and that the main process is essentially waiting forever for something that will never come from the `results` queue. The child processes crashed because of a typo in the call of `function` from `worker`: I wrote `agrument` instead of `argument`.

The child process returned a `NameError: name 'agrument' is not defined`, which won't be displayed in the console until the program terminates. But as I mentioned before the program is not responding and interrupting the IPython kernel has no effect. I must restart the kernel, which erases the error message and prevents me from recovering it.

My question is thus if there is a way to recover such child process error messages in such cases where if an error occurs, the program freezes?

Note that in practical cases the computation carried by `function` might last for a few minutes, so setting a timeout in `results.get()` is not an option.

Comment: I think the easiest way around this is to put the exception in the result queue and let the worker always exit gracefully.